# Programmatically Determine Which Objects Allow Lookup References to Them?

Tags: apex, lookup, childrelationship

I'm wondering if there is a way, via apex, to retrieve all objects that would allow a lookup field on another object to reference them.

For example, for a custom object obj1__c, I can create a lookup to the Account object. However, I can't create a lookup to the Group object. I know I would never really need to do that, but that's what I'm hoping to be able to filter out - any objects that I would not be able to lookup to from an other object. There are a ton of 'behind the scenes' objects retrieved via globalDescribe that I would love to easily filter out because you simply can't create lookup fields that reference them.

I'm aware of the describeSObjectResult class, which provides methods like isCreateable, isUpdateable, etc.. but I can't determine a definitive combination of these attributes which provides the right list of objects.

Can it be done? How?

Answer (score 1):

Often the measure of last resort, but you could try screen scraping the values from `/p/setup/field/NewCustomFieldStageManager?isdtp=p1`. It looks like that page needs a POST request with the number of form values including `entity`. The entity will have a CustomEntityDefinition Id (Keyprefix [01I](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#01I)). While you can't query these directly, you can get the IDs from [CustomObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customobject.htm) via the Tooling API.

Otherwise the data is right there on the `DomainEnumOrId` select.

```
<select  id="DomainEnumOrId" name="DomainEnumOrId">
<option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="Account">Account</option>
<option value="01I70000000UvT3">Assessment Summary</option>
<option value="Asset">Asset</option>
<option value="01I70000000BCBt">Attendence</option>
<option value="BackgroundOperation">Background Operation</option>
<option value="01I70000000IDur">BatchQueue</option>
<option value="01I70000000BIsH">Blackout Period</option>
<option value="BusinessHours">Business Hours</option>
<option value="Campaign">Campaign</option>
<!-- ... -->
<option value="01I70000000IDaw">Vehicle</option>
<option value="01I70000000BCC3">Vendor/Partner</option>
<option value="01I70000000BCC4">Vendor Team Member</option>
<option value="Community">Zone</option>
</select>
```

A number of standard objects will be referenced by name rather than Id.